# Are My Ocean Currents Realistic for a Supercontinent?

Tags: science-based, ocean, currents

I followed tutorials online and drew out my ocean currents. However I don’t have a strong grasp on the concept.

My world is primarily Earth-like with a retrograde spin and an axial tilt of 174 degrees.

**For my planet are my currents realistic what are the errors if any?**

[image: Photo of the map, with ocean current drawn as lines]
[image: Digital version of the map]

Comment: I tried to enhance your map. It's OK, but could be a lot better. Could you re-take the picture with higher resolution and try to avoid the shadow falling across it? It would also help if you could color in where the land is (we can use white for the oceans). Thanks!

Comment: Map has been updated. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Anubia-Bastet Incredibly much better! Does red lines mean warm currents and blue lines cold currents? Why are some colored lines moving through the continent? Are they lines you didn't manage to erase ^^ (damn colored pencils!) ?

Comment: Yes red is warm blue is cold. The lines running through the continent is the ITZ for summer and winter. I was following an Artifexian tutorial.

Comment: With an axial tilt of almost 180 degrees I think that the relative heat flux of extremely long intense summer/winter(s) in both the northern and southern hemispheres might produce currents very different to those seen on earth. Quite probably the currents would be more intense, and almost certainly in some regions there would be a significant seasonal variation in current flow.

Comment: @Anubia-Bastet, I've taken your photo, flattened it (you were looking at a 8° angle, apparently :p), redrew it digitally and added it to your question, along with the legend you gave me (it is often useful to avoid misunderstandings). Consider this picture your own, so do what you want with it!

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can see with the map as it is and without any depth indication, is that perhaps the small gulfs (top center and bottom right). One would expect in general those areas to be more shallow and thus be expelling warmer currents. Ex: the Gulf Stream and Alaskan Currents in reality.

[image]